# How to forge an operation of kind reveal along with operation of kind transaction using Taquito?

Tags: operation, taquito, reveal, inject

I am using methods such as forgeOperations, injectOperation provided by '@taquito/rpc' package.

However, this method works for already revealed accounts to complete the transfer between two tz1 accounts.

But, the above approach doesn't work if a tz1 account is transferring for the first time. I came to know that we should do reveal operation first before transaction operation.

How could we forge reveal and transaction operations at once and fulfil the requirement?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just append the reveal operation to the contents of the (batched) operation you'd like to inject.

Here is a code snipped extracted from some TS code we wrote:

```
    let header = await getInjectionHeader(tk, injectionBranchOffset);
    level = header.level;
    let source = await tk.signer.publicKeyHash();
    let contract = await tk.rpc.getContract(source);
    let counter = parseInt(contract.counter || '0', 10)
    let contents: Array<RPCOperation> = []; // This will contain the contents of the TX

    let revealEstimate = await tk.estimate.reveal();
    if (revealEstimate !== undefined) { // Pk revelation needed. Put it at the beginning
      let publicKey = await tk.signer.publicKey();
      let revealParams = {
        fee: revealEstimate.suggestedFeeMutez,
        gasLimit: revealEstimate.gasLimit,
        storageLimit: revealEstimate.storageLimit
      };
      let rpcRevealOperation = await createRevealOperation(revealParams, source, publicKey);
      counter++;
      contents.push(({ ...rpcRevealOperation, source, counter: counter } as RPCOperation))
    }
    let len = transfersParams.length;
    // process all TXs (enforce sequentiality and ordering with an aux function)
    let processTX = async function (i: number): Promise<void> {
      if (i >= len) return;
      let transferParams = transfersParams[i];
      let estimate = await tk.estimate.transfer(transferParams);
      const rpcTransferOperation = await createTransferOperation({
        ...transferParams,
        fee: estimate.suggestedFeeMutez,
        gasLimit: estimate.gasLimit,
        storageLimit: estimate.storageLimit
      });
      counter++;
      let v = {
        ...rpcTransferOperation,
        source,
        parameter: transferParams.parameter,
        counter: counter,
      };
      contents.push(v);
      await processTX(i + 1);
    }
    await processTX(0);
    let op = objToString({
      branch: header.hash,
      contents: contents
    })
    let forgedOp = await tk.rpc.forgeOperations(op)
    let signOp = await tk.signer.sign(forgedOp, new Uint8Array([3]));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to understand `parseInt(contract.counter || '0', 10)`
May I know why are you using `|| 0, 10` here ?
I am using `(Number(contract.counter) + 1).toString()` as logic to assign counter for the operation. Correct me if I am wrong. @iguerNL